Nextjs-issues with inconsistent view height in mobile?
I'm working on a React component that displays a split-screen modal. The modal has two sections: one that slides down from the top and another that slides up from the bottom. I'm encountering an issue where using vh units results in inconsistent heights on mobile browsers, particularly when there are dynamic UI elements like the browser's address bar.
Problem:
I initially used calc() with vh units to set the height of the bottom modal content and background. This worked fine on desktop, but on mobile devices, it causes the modal to cover elements that should remain visible.
When I switched to using h-screen and mt-[295px], it seemed to resolve the issue, but it also covered the buttons in the space between the top and bottom sections.
Current Code:
This is the code I'm currently using for the bottom section:
import React, {ReactNode} from 'react';
import SplitScreenModal from '../../ui/splitScreenModal';

interface PortalModalProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  mainContent: ReactNode; // Main content as a prop
  footerContent: ReactNode; // Footer content as a prop
}

const PortalModal: React.FC<PortalModalProps> = ({
  isOpen,
  onClose,
  mainContent,
  footerContent,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SplitScreenModal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={onClose}
        topChildren={
          <>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-[130px] bg-black bg-opacity-55 backdrop-blur-md">
              <button
                onClick={onClose}
                className="absolute top-0 mt-6 mr-6 right-0 w-[20px] h-[20px] flex items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 z-50"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  className="h-[12px] w-[12px] text-gray-600"
                  viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                >
                  <path
                    fillRule="evenodd"
                    d="M10 8.586l-4.95-4.95a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414L8.586 10l-4.95 4.95a1 1 0 001.414 1.414L10 11.414l4.95 4.95a1 1 0 001.414-1.414L11.414 10l4.95-4.95a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L10 8.586z"
                    clipRule="evenodd"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
              <img
                className="absolute top-0 mt-20"
                src="/arrow-down.svg"
                alt="Jewel Logo"
                width={250}
              />
            </div>
          </>
        }
        bottomChildren={
          <>
            {/* this is the background with blur  */}
            <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-[calc(100vh-295px)] bg-black bg-opacity-55 backdrop-blur-md"></div>
            {/* this is where the content of the bottom modal is stored  */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-[calc(100vh-295px)] px-10">
              <img
                className="absolute top-0 -mt-24 ml-15"
                src="/hand-pointer.webp"
                alt="Jewel Logo"
                width={250}
              />

              {/* Main Content */}
              <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-grow -mt-32">
                <div className="bg-greeting-gradient backdrop-blur-lg p-6 rounded-2xl shadow-lg">
                  {mainContent} {/* Dynamic Main Content */}
                </div>
              </div>

              {/* Footer */}
              <div className="absolute bottom-0 mb-20 left-0 w-full p-4 text-center">
                {footerContent} {/* Dynamic Footer Content */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default PortalModal;

looks as expected on desktop:

but not on mobile:
Safari

Chrome

Steps I Tried:
Changed h-[calc(100vh-395px)] to h-screen and used mt-[295px]: This worked to some extent, but it covered buttons that should be clickable in the space between the top and bottom modals.
{/* this is the background with blur  */}
<div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen mt-[295px] bg-black bg-opacity-55 backdrop-blur-md"></div>
{/* this is where the content of the bottom modal is stored  */}
<div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full h-screen mt-[295px] px-10">


Can you create a sandbox for this? It would be easier to debug...
